# Rails nested attributes not displayed in SHOW/not saving parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-forms

I can't seem to get the hang of routes when it comes to nested parameters and the controllers for them. Later edit - routes seemed fine, but parent_id is not saved

In my routes I have

```
   resources :galleries do
     resources :album
   end
```

Then  show in controller

```
def show
  @albums = Album.find(params[:id])
  @photos = @albums.photos.all

end

def index
  @albums = Album.includes(:photos).all


end

def new
   @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
   @album = @gallery.albums.build
   @photos = @album.photos.build
end

def create
   @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
   @album = @gallery.albums.new(album_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @album.save
       params[:photos]['image'].each do |a|
          @photo = @album.photos.create!(:image => a, :album_id => @album.id)
       end
       format.html { redirect_to gallery_path(@gallery.id), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
```

Models are like this

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :albums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums
end
```

In my form for galleries, I see fine all galleries column values.
Now I am trying to display a list of its albums like this for starters, but nothing shows up:

```
<% @gallery.albums.each do |album| %>   
  <%= album.name %>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", album, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

It turns out that the parent_id of the gallery is not being saved when I create a new album

I call the album creation like this

`<%= link_to 'New Album', new_gallery_album_path(@galleries.id) %>`

which leads to this url http://localhost:3000/galleries/1/albums

I am not exactly sure what is missing from the create definition in order for the gallery_id to be saved when I save the album

Later edit

Console before applying @Esther's suggestion

> Gallery Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE
>   "galleries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.0ms) 
>   BEGIN   SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "albums" ("band", "gallery_id",
>   "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id" 
>   [["ban d", "test"], ["gallery_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-18
>   21:09:59.805397"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-18 21:09:59.805397"]]
>   (0.0ms)  COMMIT    (0.0ms)  BEGIN

And after modifying the controller to use `@gallery.albums.create(album_params)` instead of `@gallery.albums.create`

> Gallery Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE
>   "galleries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>          (0.0ms)  BEGIN
>         SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "albums" ("band", "gallery_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id" 
>   [["ban
>       d", "new"], ["gallery_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-19 18:28:41.093138"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-19 18:28:41.093138"]]
>          (0.0ms)  COMMIT
>          (0.0ms)  BEGIN
>          (1.0ms)  COMMIT
>          (0.0ms)  BEGIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "parent_id is not saved", do you mean `gallery_id` is not being saved to `album`?

If yes, my first thought is I think you should change this line of code in your album create method from `@album = @gallery.albums.new(album_params)` to `@album = @gallery.albums.create(album_params)`. This immediately creates the album with the existing params in `album_params` which I hope includes the `gallery_id` in it before you proceed with adding the photos to the album.

Secondly, can you please update your question with the logs from the console so that we can confirm what's in the `album_params`.

Comment: Thank you @esther
Was not aware that create goes like that, but now I learned this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like there aren't any album records associated with this gallery. You can confirm by printing the count out or with a debug statement.

```
# Example:
There are <%= @albums.count %> albums associated with this gallery.

# For debugging only:
<%= debug @albums %>
```

You can also see this in the console.

```
@gallery.albums.count 
@gallery.albums.any?
```

And if you think something is awry you can check for records in the database directly (run `rails db` to connect to your database using the same credentials) and then you can execute SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM albums WHERE gallery_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @coreyward
I saw them being created with that gallery_id but upon selecting they do not show up indeed. So then there's something else Ifishy in my create/paths and so on. Will look there then.
Also thanks for the formatting. Getting the hang of it as well